# CodeIgniter removing index.php from url

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, config

I know this question has been asked a number of times.
However, I still wasn't able to get rid of index.php url. It is preventing me to access my controller directly.

I am current using `CodeIgniter 2.2.2`.
And the following is my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**application/config:**

```
//  Find the below code

$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO"

//  Replace it as

$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

Any Idea? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Are you using wamp or xampp?

Comment: I am using wamp right now, but currently I would like to be able to access in production as well. (Prod currently running linux apache)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally fixed my problem. I would like to share my answer to all of you.
I am currently using a mac, my rename my .htaccess file into htaccess.txt
And had the following code inside htaccess:

    RewriteEngine On

```
#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
#RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]


</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Then make sure Apache is reading the htaccess.txt file by doing this:

1. Uncomment the following line on your httpd.conf
2. Go inside to the extra/httpd-default.conf file and change this line of code: `AccessFileName .htaccess`
   to `AccessFileName htaccess.txt`
3. Restart Apache server
4. Inside your config, make sure to leave 'base_url' empty (index page can still be there, doesn't matter). And $config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';

Hope this can help others out there!

Answer (score 1):

Use below code in your .htacess

```
   DirectoryIndex index.php
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
# Hide the application and system directories by redirecting the request to index.php
RewriteRule ^(application|system|\.svn) index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem before. this is what i did

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

then go to config.php and remove the index.php

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
//change it to
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

If your using wamp make sure you have apache mod rewrite enabled.

This htaccess is good for wamp or xampp

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Make sure it is placed on the main directory.

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

**From the [CI User Manual](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html):**

Index.php file will be included as default in your URLs.

**Example:**

```
example.com/index.php/controller
```

**How can you change?**

You can use rewrite rule in .htaccess for removing index.php from the URLs

**Example from [User Guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html):**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Using the "negative" method in which everything is redirected except the specified items.

One last thing make you are using index_page as empty location application/config/config.php:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

In last if you are still facing issue change uri_protocol `AUTO` to `REQUEST_URI`.

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";
```

Comment: @wolfgang1983 got it bro

Comment: I looked at this guide before, didn't help.

Comment: @cs-learning-101 also change $config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"; if its auto

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

on your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

and `$config['index_page'] = '';`

worked for me